# Smoothly incement a number over a duration of time

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

So I've got this counter and it needs to increment a number by 75 every 60 seconds.  The code I have below does this fine but due to rounding some numbers stay up longer than others, and some numbers are skipped.

I'd rather have this to smoothly/evenly count to get the same end result. I know I would need to somehow calculate the `setInterval` timer number, but I'm not sure what to get that.

```
(function(){
    //Numbers
    var num = 0;
    var perMinute = 75;
    var perSecond = perMinute / 60;

    //Element selection
    var count = document.getElementById("count");

    function update(){

        //Add the per-second value to the total
        num += perSecond;

        //Display the count rounded without a decimal
        count.innerHTML = Math.round(num);
    }

    //Run the update function once every second
    setInterval(update, 1000);
})();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/9atym/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving your rounding seemed to fix this (Edit: No it doesn't. See the jsfiddle example of a better fix I put below).

```
(function(){
//Numbers
var num = 0;
var perMinute = 75;
var perSecond = perMinute / 60;

//Element selection
var count = document.getElementById("count");

function update(){

    //Add the per-second value to the total
    num += Math.round(perSecond);

    //Display the count rounded without a decimal
    count.innerHTML = num;
}

//Run the update function once every second
setInterval(update, 1000/perSecond);
})();
```

Edit: a proper fix - http://jsfiddle.net/4y2y9/1/

Comment: You're welcome. But I bet that is the very next thing you would have tried anyway ;)

Comment: I just sat down to my lunch and had another look at this and I realise I just added a stupid bug to your code! By rounding perSecond from 1.25 to 1 the counter is just going to count seconds. For some reason I thought there was an extra step between perSecond being applied to the number and it's generation.

As such I would recommend you just increase your counter increment to 1 and set your setInterval to setInterval(update, 800); as 1/1.25 is 0.8

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link with the fix I mentioned above.

Comment: Oh wow, good catch thanks!  I was about to send it off to the people who need this.  How about we just do `1000/perMinute` as the interval instead so we aren't hard-coding numbers. - http://jsfiddle.net/4y2y9/1/

Comment: I meant `1000 / perSecond` not `perMinute` - the fiddle link has the correct code!  I also edited your answer to reflect this change.

Comment: You're right that's a much better idea, that way your variable stays valid.

Answer (score 2):

Never rely on `Timeout` or `Interval` to be accurate. Instead, save the "start time" and compare it to the current time.

```
(function() {
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        perMinute = 75,
        perMS = perMinute/60000,
        count = document.getElementById('count');
    function update() {
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime()-start;
        count.innerHTML = Math.round(elapsed*perMS);
    }
    setInterval(update,1000);
})();
```

Note that you can adjust the `1000` to vary "smooth" the counter is (more important for bigger values of `perMinute`) and it will always work perfectly, to within the resolution's overshoot.

Comment: I understand your changes, but this will still skip numbers.  it counts up: 1,3,4,5,6,8... see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9atym/2/ - Also, for what this will be used for complete accuracy isn't that important.  It's mostly used to drive home a point.

Comment: This is why I said to adjust the `1000`. Change it to `100` and it hits all the numbers.